# Prevent image swap from Google Share?

Tags: google-plus

So, in the Google Share API, when I click inthe button, the popup appears. The texto, title and image appear as it should be but I noticed there was a button that allowed me to change the image. How do I remove it? Here's the image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove it. You're options are to ignore it. Or only have a single image on the page so the user can't choose anything else. Note that they can still choose to have not photo at all.